# ImproperlyConfigured. View is missing a QuerySet. Define model, queryset, or override get_queryset()

Tags: python, django

This is the error i am having :- ImproperlyConfigured at /attendanceattendance/add
AddAttendance is missing a QuerySet. Define AddAttendance.model, AddAttendance.queryset, or
override AddAttendance.get_queryset().

This is my models.py

```
class StudentAttendance(models.Model):
    StudentName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    StudentRoll = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lecturesAttended = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    TotalLectures = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.StudentName
    
    def save(self,*args,**Kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.StudentName)
        super().save(*args,**Kwargs)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")
    
    class Meta():
         ordering = ['StudentName']

This is my view

class AddAttendance(generic.CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_model = forms.AttendanceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'attendance/attendance.html'

This is my urls

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'attendance'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^attendance/add',views.AddAttendance.as_view(),name='attend')
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QNTs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should look like this

```
class AddAttendance(generic.CreateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    form = forms.AttendanceForm
    model = StudentAttendance
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'attendance/attendance.html'
```

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured at /attendanceattendance/add
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of AddAttendance) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.

Comment: thanks it worked but i didnt had to use model instead i removed model and used form_class = forms.AttendanceForm

Comment: I have one more question can you tell me that in which case do we need to write function like save and write queryset

Comment: You would want to update or get a queryset if you are working with or may need to work with multiple objects. Saving or getting an individual record would not really require a queryset